# Remove space in print statement in python

Tags: dictionary, key-value, space

While using the below print command:

```
print(k,':',dict[k])
```

I get the output as shown below but in the output, i want to remove the space between the key and colon.How to do it?

Current Output:

```
Sam : 40
```

Required Output:

```
Sam: 40
```

Comment: use `print("{}: {}".format(k, dict[k]))`

Answer (score 0):

You could try printing a single string consisting of a concatenation:

```
print(k + ': ' + dict[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

The python print() statement has a separator parameter that defaults to a space. So the comma-separated values that you are passing into it serve as arguments each of which will get separated by white-space while printing.
I think what you are looking for is

```
print(name, ": ", "40", sep = '')
>>> Sam: 40
```

Simply specifying the "sep" parameter solves your issue.